# Problem with download File Rar And Zip With Controller.File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have service you can upload your file and after that with a method you can download it.
It working with any type of data except RAR and ZIP When download it first the size of the file CHANGE increase about 1MB and it does not have extension, you should download it and add extension then extract it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Download Attachment
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="attachmentId"></param>
    [HttpGet("{attachmentId}/download")]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public ActionResult<string> DownloadFile([FromRoute] int attachmentId)
    {
        var result = _service.DownloadFile(_user.UserId, attachmentId);
        return File(result.file, result.mimeType, result.AttachmentName, true);
    }
```

and this is the response in swagger:

[image]

and the browser download box:

[image]

Comment: Is the `[.net-core]` tag a mistake (since it's the odd one out)?

Comment: Presumably `result.AttachmentName` doesn't have the extension.

Comment: actually `result.AttachmentName` its just the name but i send it the mime type of the data as `result.mimeType`

Comment: its work well with other types like mp4, png, jpg and ... except rar and zip

Comment: I found in some way as you say @Llama i send extension of file in `result.AttachmentName` and work for rar and zip but im not sure its correct or not